# Go back a directory with $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]

Tags: php

I am trying this code to try and go back 1 directory from the document root

What am I doing wrong?

```
$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/../config.ini"
```

Comment: how are you using that, currently its just a string

Answer (score 0):

The document root would be the just a string. You would perhaps want to do the following:

```
function nav_one_back($filepath){
    return preg_replace("/(\/.*){2}.$/","",$filepath);
}
```

Effectively, this takes a file path and would remove the ultimate file folder from the path.